# How to sum the column value seperated with semicolon in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with the values as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column4': ['NaN;NaN;1;4','4;8','nan']} )
print (df)
       Column4
0  NaN;NaN;1;4
1          4;8
2          nan
```

I tried with the code below to get the sum.

```
df['Sum'] = df['Column4'].apply(lambda x: sum(map(int, x.split(';'))))
```

I am getting the error message as

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'NaN'

Comment: Can you paste snippet of your data & expected output which is more legible(you can paste them in HTML snippets)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `expand=True` for `DataFrame`, convert to floats and `sum` per rows - pandas by default exclude missing values:

```
df['Sum'] = df['Column4'].str.split(';', expand=True).astype(float).sum(axis=1)
print (df)
       Column4   Sum
0  NaN;NaN;1;4   5.0
1          4;8  12.0
2          nan   0.0
```

Your solution should be changed:

```
f = lambda x: sum(int(y) for y in x.split(';') if not y in ('nan','NaN'))
df['Sum'] = df['Column4'].apply(f)
```

because if convert to float get mssing values for NaNs with another numeric:

```
df['Sum'] = df['Column4'].apply(lambda x: sum(map(float, x.split(';'))))
print (df)
       Column4   Sum
0  NaN;NaN;1;4   NaN
1          4;8  12.0
2          nan   NaN
```